# Soft Keyboard Application

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

I am working on a keyboard application like **[Go keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.emoji.gokeyboard&hl=en)**. Just one thing that I am confused about. 
In **Go keyboard** app, they uploaded all of their themes on **play store** as a separate application. Once an user downloads any theme, he/she can use it on his/her keyboard.
I do not know how can I achieve the same functionality as **GO keyboard**.

I have a Main App and different sub (theme) apps. How can I use theme apps setting on my Main App Keyboard?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would assume the theme app has a content provider that exports the theme data.  The keyboard queries it for theme data via that content provider.

Comment: So i've to learn content provider first to achieve this kind of behavior in my app.

Thanks for your help